How can I make two legends in a MATLAB figure the same size and adjust the legend marker size appropriately?
From the figure below, the following two issues are observed:

Legend font size inconsistency: Although both Legend 1 and Legend 2 are set to font size 6, they appear to display at different sizes.
Oversized legend markers: Adjusting legend2.ItemTokenSize has little effect on the size of the markers in the legend, which still appear too large.

How to solve the above problems? I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide assistance.
Thanks a lot!

This is the code for legend1:
    legend1=legend(legend_entries, ...
                          'FontName', 'Times New Roman', 'FontSize', 6,...
                          'Location', 'NorthEastoutside',...
                          'Box', 'on', 'NumColumns', 1 );
    
    set(legend1, 'Position', [0.84, 0.41, 0.1, 0.2]); 

    
    legend1.ItemTokenSize = [10, 10];

    
    legend('AutoUpdate', 'off');
   

This is the code for legend2:
if nargin > 1 && ~isempty(set_legend2)
        
        new_ax = axes('Position', get(gca, 'Position'),...
                      'Units', get(gca, 'Units'), 'Visible', 'off');
        legend2=legend(new_ax,set_legend2,plot_info.leg,...
                              'FontName', 'Times New Roman', 'FontSize', 6, ...    
                              'Location', 'northwest', ...
                              'Box', 'off', 'NumColumns', 2 );
   
        set(legend2, 'Position', [0.55, 0.75, 0.1, 0.1]); 
         
        % 调整图例大小和位置
        legend2.ItemTokenSize = [10, 10]; 
    end


I’m sorry to criticize, but someone has got to say this. That graph is unreadable. It has way too much in it. The markers described in legend 1 cannot be recognized in the plot, they all overlap, the earlier ones are below the later ones and hidden. If you remove color, it’s just one giant ink blob, so maybe marker shape can be left out, just use small dots of different color. Hopefully if the dots are small enough you can see them all. Maybe you need to plot only a subset of measurements, or statistics of those measurements. The bright green, magenta, cyan and red markers are not described.

Thank you for your feedback. You're correct—this is a test image, and I will continue to improve it. The image displays correctly on my end and for others, but I appreciate your points about the marker overlap and color usage. I'll refine the graph to make it clearer.

I don't think the font sizes are actually different, I think it's just because legend1 has entries in all capital letters which appear larger. They are both using font size 6. If I snip bits of the image together it looks like the actual character height is the same between the two, I think your (1) is a non-issue.

For the marker sizing, you can control it independently by setting the MarkerSize property of the line objects within the legend:
% Create a plot
figure(1); clf; hold on;
plot( 1:N, cos((1:N)*2/N), '-x' );
plot( 1:N, rand(1,N), '-o' );
plot( 1:N, sin((1:N)*2/N), '-d' );

% Create the legend, use the 2nd output to get the graphics objects
[leg,obj] = legend( {'cos','rand','sin'} );
% Find the line objects and change their marker properties
lines = findobj(obj,'type','line');
set(lines,'Markersize',15);

Noted by @Ramashalanka in the comments, the multi-output syntax for legend has been recommended against for a while now (although MathWorks seem to have dropped the warning testing in 22b), here's an alternate method for getting the lines handles to then change the markers in the same way:
% Create the legend
leg = legend( {'cos','rand','sin'} );
% Find the line objects and change their marker properties
lines = cellfun( @(x)findobj(gcf,'displayname',x), leg.String );
set(lines,'Markersize',15);



Nice answer, +1, and I'm not sure how to do it without multiple ouputs but note "R2014b: Returning multiple outputs using this syntax is no longer recommended:
[lgd,icons,plots,txt] = legend(__)
This syntax creates a legend that does not support some functionality introduced in R2014b or later. For example, you cannot add a title to the legend or specify the number of legend columns. Also, the legend does not automatically update when you add or remove data series from the axes."

@Ramashalanka weird, there is no warning in R22b where I was testing... I've edited my answer to add an approach which doesn't rely on the 2nd output of legend()

Thank you so much for your detailed response. I tested your method, and it solved the issue. Thanks a lot.
